# the correct way to deal with spaces in a pattern for grep

Tags: grep

The latest [grep 3.8](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/) emits a warning on a pattern where whitespace is
escaped with a backslash

```bash
$ grep "bla\ bazz" t 
/tmp/bin/grep: warning: stray \ before white space
...
```

whereas grep 3.6 does not complain. What's the correct way to deal with such a pattern ? Just do not escape the space? I.e.

```bash
$ grep "bla bazz" t
```

Are there some more exotic `grep`'s out there, which would incorrectly deal with unescaped space? Maybe, different quotas to be used to make it all nice and clean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You only need to escape a space to protect it from the shell, not for `grep`. Space characters aren't special for regular expressions, they are only special in the shell since they are what the shell uses to define parameters. So if your pattern is unquoted (which is a bad idea), you need the space:

```
$ echo 'foo bar' | grep -c foo\ bar
1
```

That ensures that she shell doesn't parse `foo bar` as two arguments, passing the `bar` as a file name to `grep`. You can see this in action with `set -x`:

```
$ set -x
$ echo 'foo bar' | grep -c foo\ bar
+ grep -c 'foo bar'
+ echo 'foo bar'
1
```

While if you don't escape, you get:

```
$ echo 'foo bar' | grep -c foo bar
+ grep -c foo bar
+ echo 'foo bar'
grep: bar: No such file or directory
```

However, if you quote your pattern, that will protect it from the shell and no escape is necessary:

```
$ echo 'foo bar' | grep -c "foo bar"
+ grep --color -c 'foo bar'
+ echo 'foo bar'
1
```

or

```
$ echo 'foo bar' | grep -c 'foo bar'
+ grep --color -c 'foo bar'
+ echo 'foo bar'
1
```

This is why `grep` now warns you when it sees a literal (quoted) `\` before a space: it is warning you that `\`  just becomes   (a space) sine there is nothing to escape and therefore the `\` is pointless. It will do the same for any other character that is escaped when it isn't "escapeable":

```
$ echo 'foo bar' | grep -c "f\oo\ bar"
+ grep --color -c 'f\oo\ bar'
+ echo 'foo bar'
grep: warning: stray \ before o
grep: warning: stray \ before white space
1
```

Answer (score 14):

The space character in not special in regular expressions (except in `perl`-like ones when the `x` flag is enabled), so must not be escaped. `\` followed by a space yields unspecified results in POSIX regexps.

So you want:

```
grep 'blah bazz'
```

If you want to make it more visible, you can use:

```
grep 'blah[ ]bazz'
```

More generally you should not put `\` is front of characters that are not regular expression operators. Where `X` is not a regular expression operator, `\X` may very well be, if not now maybe in a future versions. For instance, `+`, `<`, `d` are not basic regular expression operators , but `\<`, `\+` and `\d` are for some `grep` implementations.

You may want to use `\` followed by a space in:

```
grep -P '(?x)  foo \  bar'
```

```
perl -ne 'print if / foo \  bar /x'
```

To match on `foo bar` when the `x` flag is on. But even there, you'd rather do:

```
grep -P '(?x)  foo [ ] bar'
```

To make it more legible. The whole point of the `x` flag is to make regexps more legible like:

```
perl -ne 'print if m{
  \d{4}   # year
  - \d{2} # month
  - \d{2} # day
  [ ] (foo | bar | baz)}x'
```

vs

```
perl -ne'print if/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} (foo|bar|baz)/'
```

You can't use `[ ]` with the `xx` flag (in perl 5.26+, not PCRE) though, where spaces are also ignored inside bracket expressions.

See `perldoc perlre` for details of perl regular expressions, and `man pcrepattern` for the PCRE (perl-compatible regular expressions) ones. Using `\Q \E` is another option.

In any case, while space is a special character in the syntax of the shell and not in regular expressions, there are a number of characters that are special in both such as `*`, `\`, `(`, `)`, `?`, `$`, `^`, `[`, `]`, so would need to be escaped for both if meant to be matched literally, preferably with quotes for the shell, and with `\` (or `[...]`, or `\Q...\E` in perl-like ones) for the regexps.

As `\` and `$` are common in regular expressions, and those characters are still special to the shell inside double quotes, it's a good habit to put regexps in single quotes rather than double quotes. You'd only use double quotes if you needed to expand a shell parameter into the regular expression as in `grep "^$var"` or needed to include a `'` in the regexp.

To `grep` literal strings as opposed to regular expressions, or in other words, to escape *every* regular expression operators, you can use the `-F` (for `F`ixed string) option to `grep`. For instance:

```
grep -F 'blah\ bazz'
```

Would look for lines that  contain `blah\ bazz`.

Comment: both answers I  got are good, I only can accept one, sorry.

Answer (score -1):

From 3.8 release notes (https://savannah.gnu.org/news/?id=10191):

> Regular expressions with stray backslashes now cause warnings, as
> their unspecified behavior can lead to unexpected results.   For
> example, '\a' and 'a' are not always equivalent
> https://bugs.gnu.org/39678.  Similarly, regular expressions or
> subexpressions that start with a repetition operator now also cause
> warnings due to their unspecified behavior; for example, *a(+b|{1}c)
> now has three reasons to warn.  The warnings are intended as a
> transition aid; they are likely to be errors in future releases.

Comment: How does this answer the question? The question already states this behaviour happens in 3.8

Comment: Because I thought adding the reason for the behavior change would help. OP asks "What's the correct way to deal with such a pattern" and the note says "their unspecified behavior can lead to unexpected results" --> so don't use spurious backslashes